# When connected to BranchA via git checkout BranchA, if I do git pull BranchB then will BranchB code get pulled into BranchA?

Tags: git

When I am connected to `BranchA` via `git checkout BranchA` and do a `git pull` or `git pull origin BranchA` or `git pull BranchA`, then code from remote `BranchA` will get pulled into local `BranchA`.

However, while connected to local `BranchA` via `git checkout BranchA`, suppose I do `git pull BranchB` or `git pull master`, then will git try to pull code from that respective branch on the server into the local `BranchA`?

Comment: "connected to" = checked out locally?

Comment: Yes that's right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

The fetch part will be the same in both cases : fresh refs are fetched from remote.

However (`git pull` being `git fetch` + `git merge`), the merge part will be different.

Granted, it depends on your config, but `git pull branchB` in most settings will consist of

```
git fetch
git merge origin/branchB
```

Comment: Ok so git fetch is always across all branches and not targeted to one particular branch?

Comment: Yes, by default it fetches all refs (branches) from the remote. (or from *all* remotes if you added `--all`)

Answer (score 1):

From the `git pull` docs (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#_description):

> Incorporates changes from a remote repository into the current branch.

This is commonly used to update a branch with changes from the corresponding branch on the remote; but what it is defined to do is incorporate changes from the remote (any such changes you specify) into the current branch.

As an aside, while it seems clear what you mean, your terminology suggests some possible confusion about git concepts.  You don't really "connect" to this branch or that branch in git.  In git-speak you would just say that the branch is checked out.

To be fair, this terminology is a little murky in that you can have a branch checked out, or you can have no branch checked out (detached head state) and simply have a commit checked out - even if that commit is the tip of a branch.  But in either case, what the symbolic ref `HEAD` points to is what you would say is checked out, and if that's a branch - which it usually is - then `pull` will incorporate changes into that branch.